# Adding legend to a multiple column graph in R

Tags: r, graph, legend

I have been trying desperately to add a legend to a graph I wanted to produce, following many of the answers to previous questions, but have until now been unsuccessful.

Could anybody explain to me what I have to add to the following line of code to get a legend (or possibly also explain why it doesn't generate it automatically (in ELI5 mode - I really could not grasp the aes() argument))? :-)

---

```
ggplot(dfm_hl, aes(stringr::str_wrap(document, 15), group = 1)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = positive), color = "darkred") +
  geom_point(aes(y = negative), color = "steelblue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = positive), color = "darkred") +
  geom_line(aes(y = negative), color = "steelblue") +
  labs(title="Sentiment Across Industries", y="Sentiment (%)", x="Industry") +
  theme(text = element_text(size=8), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5))
```

Dataframe in question [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7qIX.png)
Output I have been getting[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYfUa.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you please make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)). Its considered bad practice to present images of data. These links should be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Comment: > dput(head(dfm_hl))
structure(list(document = c("Agriculture, Forestry, And Fishing", 
"Construction", "Finance, Insurance, And Real Estate", "Manufacturing", 
"Mining", "Retail"), positive = c(4.75651189127973, 5.44488711819389, 
4.68391167192429, 4.71798628221349, 5.32380732887762, 4.58885941644562
), negative = c(1.58550396375991, 1.72642762284197, 1.37539432176656, 
1.55823400146501, 1.5326112007375, 1.39257294429708)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Please add the `dput(drm_hl)` output into the **question** with three back ticks before and after the output. Have you checked also that this reduced dataset reproduces the problem? You may need to include more data or a selected sample of the data.

Answer (score 0):

hey bud Run everything in the console and you should be able to use:

```
legend(x = 0, y = -1, legend = c("item1", "item2"), col = c("black", "red"), 
       pch = c(1, 16))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that - I tried that also before, but it produces the following errors:

Error: Can't add `o` to a ggplot object.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  invalid graphics state
2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  invalid graphics state